# How to get all windows being show on screen?

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, win32-process

I asked a similar kind of question last month but unfortunately i did not get a single response to that question. I am asking it again.
In one of my projects i want to get all the windows being shown on screen. I tried this code

```
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();
if (proc.MainWindowHandle!=IntPtr.Zero)
                {

                GetWindowPlacement(proc.MainWindowHandle, ref placement);
                if (proc.ProcessName!="McUICnt" && proc.ProcessName!="devenv" && proc.ProcessName!="DCSHelper" && proc.ProcessName!="explorer")
                {
                    if (placement.showCmd == 1)
                    {
                        handles[temp] = proc.MainWindowHandle;
                        GetWindowRect(proc.MainWindowHandle, ref rct);
                        rect[temp] = rct;
                        temp++;
                        MessageBox.Show(proc.ProcessName.ToString());
                    }
                }

                }
```

As you can see i have put a check for `McUICnt,devenv`. `placement.cmd==1` checks for the windows with normal state. But McUICnt and devenv are also passing that condition but are not showing on the screen. When i run again program then i get new process like stated above. 
How to get all the windows being shown on the screen right now?

**UPDATE:**
When I use EnumWindows i use this code

```
EnumWindows(new EnumWindowsProc(EnumTheWindows), IntPtr.Zero);
```

and

```
protected static bool EnumTheWindows(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
        {

            int size = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
            RECT rct = new RECT();
            if (size++ > 0 && IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
                GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, size);
                MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
                handles[tempHandle] = hWnd;
                GetWindowRect(hWnd, ref rct);
                rect[tempHandle] = rct;
                tempHandle++;

            }
            return true;
        }
```

But it also shows minimized windows. Even I have put a check `IsWindowVisible`

Comment: Call `EnumWindows` to get all top level windows

Comment: @DavidHeffernan please see my edit. I have tried your suggestion.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes it has worked for me. But it is showing minimized windows also. Even i have put a check  IsWindowVisible.

Comment: Use `IsIconic` to test for minimized windows

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that and its working but a last issue with that is 2 more extra windows are showing "Program Manager" and "DataCardMoniter".

Comment: Program Manager is the desktop window. Not sure about DataCardMonitor. Looks like some T-mobile software.

Comment: Ok for this time i shall put a check on these two windows.
 Thanks for your continued support and help @DavidHeffernan